# Split Multiple Columns into Multiple Rows based on a condition

Tags: sql, split, teradata

I have a table with this structure.

The first table is the main table and 2 and 3 are the same table with the split columns.

[Table Structure][image: 1]

I have a case statement to satisfy, so if the case statement is satisfied then i split the rows. That is column 2 and column 3 as new value in the 2nd table and column 4 and column 5 will be the new value in 3rd table.

I can't figure out what SQL query I would use to get a result set like that

Thanks!

Comment: Is "AnsweToQuestion2" somehow in the data?

Comment: I have edited the question now. Can you please check the question now?

Comment: however why are you still splitting for John? value2 is = 0 for him

Comment: @eshirvana I have attached an image to explain in a more clear way. Can you please check that image and let me know if it is clear now?

Comment: @eshirvana I have attached the image now. Can you please check it now.

Comment: Please post your sample data and desired results as text, I can't even begin to read that image.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want to do,
the first select returns all rows for F_other_p ,Pro_other_p
but second select after union only returns FT_prc_P ,pro_other_prc_p , if the conditions are met , so it looks like you are splitting it :

```
select Factor,F_other_p newval1,Pro_other_p newval2
union all
select Factor,FT_prc_P newval1,pro_other_prc_p newval2
where pro_other_p <> 0
and pro_other_prc_p <> 0
```

Comment: still my answer is relevant , doesn't this answer your question?

Comment: there are no such id and username columns